# Use key mapping only after specific characters

Tags: c++, vim, autocomplete, neovim

I want to use tab to call an deoplete for autocompletion.

I currently use this in my vimrc for that:

```
inoremap <silent><expr> <Tab> pumvisible() ? "\<C-n>" : deoplete#mappings#manual_complete()
```

Is it possible to have this mapping only if the cursor is positioned after certain characters like "." or "::"?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that's not a built-in feature of that plugin?

Comment: When you're using [deoplete-clang](https://github.com/zchee/deoplete-clang), this should already be working. Alternatively, you could give YouCompleteMe a try, as you can configure semantic triggers per filetype with this plugin.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, this is probably built into the plugin already, because it makes sense.

---

*Here's an answer to the general question:*

To trigger a mapping only when there are certain characters before the cursor,
use `:help :map-expr` with a non-jumping search. For example, this turns `x` into a
smiley when written after . or #:

```
inoremap <expr> x search('[.#]\%#', 'bcnW') ? ':-)' : 'x'
```